# Syntax Error in From clause - VB6

Tags: vb6

Having a problem getting the above Error Message.
Can anyone assist please ?

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection 
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command 
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset 
Dim RS2 As New ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Call cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & TheServer &   
          FileTypeOld & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=12345678;")

If cn.State = 0 Then cn.Open
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mov"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdTable
Set RS = cmd.Execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using an SQL statement with a Command type `adCmdTable`.  When using that command type, ADO will generate the select query internally, you are expected in this case to just specify the name of the table.

Alternatively, just remove the `cmd.CommandType = adCmdTable` line all together and keep the `select * syntax`.

Comment: Great - Thank you very much. I removed the line Cmd.CommandType.     Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need ton add this character `_` which is underscore at the end of this line

Just replace with this:

```
Call cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & TheServer & _
FileTypeOld & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=12345678;")
```

or you can merge both lines into one line without underscore, just like this

```
Call cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & TheServer & ileTypeOld & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=12345678;")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this underscore in the code. It is not showing here.